# Would a cron job to automatically optimize tables on a monthly basis be ideal?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm wondering if running the `OPTIMIZE` command via cronjob would be an intelligent move? Sometimes I forget to run optimize for months at a time.

My database is frequently using select, insert, update. It has about 45,000,000 rows.

Select uses the dateChecked column and update uses the URL column.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which is the engine of that table: InnoDB or MyISAM? And which mysql version?

Answer (score 4):

The compete and correct answer depends on which Mysql version you have and on which engine is the table.

Fast answer: no.

### MyISAM

**Short answer**
Only if you can have some downtime and want to take some risks (see below).

**Long answer**
During the optimize, the table becomes I inaccessible, and if you need to use that table (selects, inserts, etc), then it's not a good idea to perform an scheduled downtime.

### InnoDB

**Short answer**
If you have mysql 5.6.17 or above, than you may do it without downtime, but I wouldn't recommend it.

**Long answer**
Since mysql 5.6.17 that InnoDB can perform an optimize table with Online DDL, which means that selects, and even inserts, deletes and updates can be performed on the table while the optimize is running, if that is your case.
With that you can schedule an optimize on the table knowing that your system continues to run.

But it may not be safe to do it like that, as things may go wrong, and you're not with your eyes on the database to fix it ASAP. For example, you may not have free disk space for the optimize to run.

For 5.6.16 or lower, applies what I've said about myISAM.

### Conclusion

Optimize table may lock your database users from accessing the database, if your mysql version doesn't support online ddl. And even if it supports, performing an operation like that automatically needs to be done with extreme care.

Maybe create a cron that sends you an email to remember to do the optimize?

Comment: For InnoDB the answer should be *don't bother, it's not gonna help anyway*.

Comment: What did you do to get that much "Overhead"?  Delete a lot of rows?  Or is this a `PARTITIONed` table, and the number won't go away with `OPTIMIZE`?  What tool shows that "Overhead"?

Comment: @RickJames, better you ask to the user "User", who made the question.

Comment: But why do you say that, @jkavalik?

Comment: InnoDB _usually_ takes care of keeping its BTrees reasonably balanced, hence `OPTIMIZE` _rarely_ does anything useful for InnoDB tables.  Search this forum for [mysql] [optimize] -- more details are given in many answers.

Comment: @NunoPereira optimize (or more specifically rebuild) of InnoDB table is only meaningful in few limited cases - after removing many rows if you know you will not insert new ones (maybe because some housekeeping script failed and the table grew a lot beyond its usual size) or if you find out that the datafile/btree structure became really heavily fragmented for some reason and the rebuild might fix that. But running it periodically just does not cover these. If you often insert and then delete lot of rows, just keep the "free" space for the next batch of inserts.

Comment: From my experience (MySQL 5.7 on AWS RDS Aurora) 'optimize' made a 1000 times improvement - my query runs 0.2 sec instead of 3 minutes!

Answer (score 1):

The statements about:

> no need for InnoDB

... in previous comments is misleading.

I had a database (MySQL 5.7) with more than 12'000 tables and 150 GB disk usage. The server was running out of space. Running a global `OPTIMIZE` (with `mysqlcheck -o --all-databases`) reclaimed 27 GB (!) of free space.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for your contribution. If you could support your observation with some form of documentation, then this would greatly increase the acceptance of your answer. Otherwise your statement is just an observation which might be based on unknown factors. Also feel free to [roll back](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/248500/revisions) the edit I conducted to increase the readability of your answer. Good luck with your journey on DBA.SE. It's a fantastic place to be once you have managed to grasp how it works.